# UnetBootin Issues

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, compiling, unetbootin

I just built a computer, I am trying to install ubuntu 14.04 live x64, although I am having some issues. When I boot from the drive, it gives me the try ubuntu, install, check memory menu but when I try to install it says switching back to text console than turns off my screen. I am hoping its an issue that is with the way I am installing it. Could it be that my parts aren't compatible?

P.S. Computer works fine, I am able to enter BIOS easily, everything lights up

Answer (score 0):

Is there any error message? You may want to try Live DVD to see if the problem occurs. What I have experienced is the USB stick created by Unetbootin does not correctly identify the UUID, causing the boot loader to load properly but cannot go into Ubuntu.